# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(Any) -> Int' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift

I would like that the index will be equal to 1 or 2 but I got the error *

> "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(Any) -> Int' and 'Int'"

so how can I resolve this please ?

Thats my code

```
func onboardingWillTransitonToIndex(_: Int) {
        if index == 1 {
            if self.welkomBtn.alpha == 1 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations:  {
                    self.welkomBtn.alpha = 0
                })
            }
        }
    }

func onboardingDidTransitonToIndex(_: Int) {
    if index == 2 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations:  {
            self.welkomBtn.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods should be named anyway in a *swiftier* way:`onboardingWillTransiton(to index: Int)` and `onboardingDidTransiton(to index: Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions should be like

```
func onboardingWillTransitonToIndex(_ index:Int)
func onboardingDidTransitonToIndex(_ index:Int)
```

in your current code `index` is of type `(Any) -> Int` which can't be compared with 1 or 2 ( which are of `Int` type )

Answer (score 0):

`index` is not an Int, if this is a class variable, make sure its `index : Int`, otherwise, specify in the function parameter.

The error is telling you that you should only compare `Int` with `Int` and in your case, index is **not** an `Int` and `1` is.